# Is there such thing as a hybrid View that combines SurfaceView and GridView in Android?

Tags: android, game-design, grid

I am trying to develop several Android games that work on a grid system. I will need to update the game surface frequently, so using a `GridLayout` does not seem to be a good option. The frequent updates to the game surface would be similar to what you see in Plants vs Zombies: the user can interact with parts of the grid, but the sprites representing the computer opponent will always be moving until the level ends.

I want to sublcass `SurfaceView` but give it many of the built-in properties of a `GridLayout` (ex. I want to allow the user to drop a game object in a grid cell and have that object start animating within the bounds of the grid cell, so I would want row and column indexes built in to my custom `SurfaceView`) but that's a lot of work.

Do you now if something like this already exists?

Is it better to just use a "normal" `SurfaceView` and somehow keep track of where on the `SurfaceView` the grid lines should fall, maybe using a HashMap or something to track the vertices of all the grid cells? That seems like a lot of work and I don't want to reinvent the wheel if I don't have to.

I'm looking for design device or recommendations on free libraries (*.jar) that I could use to accomplish this goal efficiently. I'm coding in plain old Android Studio so no Unity access :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't subclass SurfaceView.  Use composition, not inheritance.  There's no value in subclassing it, and many basic mistakes (like overriding `onDraw()` when your goal is to draw on the Surface) are impossible if you don't.
2. The View-based UI is rendered on a separate layer from the SurfaceView's surface.  (The SurfaceView has a View as well, but generally that's just a transparent hole that the layout code uses to position things.)  Mixing View elements with stuff drawn directly on a surface is viable but trouble-prone given the wide variety of device characteristics, so mixing GridLayout and SurfaceView isn't a good idea.
3. What you have described so far doesn't sound that complicated to do, unless you try to reinvent GridLayout and all of the invalidate/measure/layout fun -- a simple regularly-spaced grid subdividing the surface should be easy.  You can even set the surface size to a fixed value with [`setFixedSize()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#setFixedSize(int,%20int)), though you still need to worry about the display aspect ratio.  [(demo)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpRaD-ij2xc)